# putting a backgroung job on ubuntu on ec2 which will work forever

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to put a job on amazon ec2 which is something like delayed job for rails server. The job has to run even when my local machine get disconnected from ec2. Is there any way I can do that. I try screen but the job gets destroyed after sometime when I disconnect from amazon ec2. Any guesses.

Answer (score 1):

use `nohup` or run from a start up script.

Screen should work and if it doesnt there program exit'ed by itself check its logs

to use screen do

`screen -S screen`

`[YOUR COMMANDS HERE]`
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

To re attach

`screen -r screen`

when you re attach there should be some error message on the screen if the program exited unexpectedly

Comment: Is there any specific way to use screen, I used it may be I used it in some wrong way. can you be bit elaborate on using screen. Initially I used nohup but I don't know why some days after is stops.

Comment: I run the command it was working till sometime but when I logout from the ec2, the command stops working as this command basically send email. When I login to the system -- and did screen -r screen, it actually shows this : 5683.screen (12/19/2013 02:54:39 PM) (Detached) can you tell where I am wrong.

Comment: try `screen -r 5683.screen`

Comment: it is basically showing the email which it sent before, there is also one more thing coming when I do screen -r screen that is :Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.

Comment: Which program is it ? It should have error logs

Comment: its not a program just a rake jobs:work command for heroku so it can run rails delayed job on ec2.